# CakePHP syntax for find conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a table called `Users` and the following find works fine:

```
$users = $this->User->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>1)));
```

However, if I try to get a list of users with `"User.id != 1" or "User.id >= 5",`  the find does not return data.

The syntax I have used is

```
$users = $this->User->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>'<> 1')));
```

AND

```
$users = $this->User->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>'>= 1')));
```

The debug query generated by Cake for the `User.id => '<> 1')` case is

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name` FROM `mesh2`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = '<>1',
```

which seems to be incorrect.

I have used the examples from Alvin's [site](http://alvinalexander.com/php/cakephp-find-conditions-cakephp-find-all-list-count).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put `>=` on the correct side of the array:

```
$this->User->find('list', array(
    'conditions'=>array('User.id >=' => 1)));
```

as documented in the "official" documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Possible keys by default, all of which are optional:

```
$params = 
        array(
        'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
        'recursive' => 1, //int
        //array of field names
        'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
        //string or array defining order
        'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
        'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
        'limit' => n, //int
        'page' => n, //int
        'offset' => n, //int
        'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
    );
```

Query:

```
$resp = find('all', $params);

debug($resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->User->find('list', array(
    'conditions'=>array('User.id >=' => true)));
```